# java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType overrides final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, verifyerror

I've created a JSF web application running on Tomcat which uses Hibernate for DB interaction. On the first time use it already throws the following exception and the web application stops working:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType overrides final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at com.bis.dao.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:48)
    at com.bis.dao.HibernateUtil.buildIfNeeded(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at com.bis.dao.CheckValidUser.validUser(CheckValidUser.java:19)
    at com.bis.bean.UserLogin.userLoginCheck(UserLogin.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpress    ionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 27 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Take a look in your pom.xml and remove the hibernate-annotations dependency, for it is provided internaly with newest hibernate-core versions

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are [facing a versioning conflict](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1010086). Hibernate's `WrappedMaterializedBlobType` has a method which is marked as `final` starting from version `3.6.2`. It seems like you have a dependency which assumes an older version of Hibernate. Upgrade all your project dependencies and you might just get rid of the error.

Comment: I change my hibernate-core dependency to 3.6.3 version and remove the annotation-3.5.6-Final, for it was already included in core